# Can I use the idea of a one handed shovel in my non-commercial project?

Tags: patent-infringement, law, infringement

I want to make a one handed shovel for my college project. I have thought of substantial modifications from what has been described here. 
The idea has already been described in patent US646472.
Will I be infringing any rights?

Answer (score 1):

The broad idea of a "one-handed shovel" is not preempted by the patent. The patent only protects what is described in the claims.

Also,  it appears you mis-typed the patent number,as that patent has nothing to do with a one-handed shovel, and would have expired about 100 years ago.

In general, though, just because a use is "non-commercial" is not a great defense to infringement.

Answer (score 1):

Spoons are one-handed shovels.  And off-patent.  Whether you would be infringing ANY in-force patents with something more complicated, like 6464272, is a complicated question that might take many hours to answer, and then the answer would never be definitive.  That's life.  But unless you sell a million on the internet, it won't make economic sense for any patent owner to sue you.

Answer (score 0):

If you were trying to refer to:

> One handed shovel for handicapped
>
> [US 6464272](https://www.google.com/patents/US6464272)

Google patents says it expired in 2006 due to non-payment of maintenance fees.